# TYPO3: CSS class selection on the RTE link dialog

Tags: class, hyperlink, typo3, typoscript, rte

How can I define a dropdown with my own css classes for all tabs on the link dialog at the TYPO3 RTE? I've done it for the first tab **page**, but I need it also on the tab **file**. Another problem is, that the dropdown disapears if I change to another tab and back again. Has someone an idea?

This is my code actually (*PageTS*):

```
RTE {
  default {
    proc {
      allowedClasses := addToList(class1, class2, class3)
    }
    buttons {
      link {
        properties {
          class {
            allowedClasses := addToList(class1, class2, class3)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  buttons {
    link < RTE.default.buttons.link
  }
}
```